# How do I pickle a dictionary containing a module & class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I need to assign a module & class to a dictionary key.  Then pickle that dictionary to file.  Then later, load the pkl file, then import & instantiate the class, based on that dictionary key value.

I've tried this:

```
import module_example
from module_example import ClassExample

dictionary = {'module': module_example, 'class': ClassExample)
```

Yet it won't store a reference to module_exmaple.py in the pkl file.

I've tried a workaround of using a string instead of the module & class name.  But that's going to lead to a mess if the module name gets refactored or location is changed down the road.

Is there anyway do this directly?  Somehow store a reference to the module & class in a dictionary, then later import & instantiate based on that reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for single class. If you want to do this in multiple modules and classes, you can extend the following code.

**module_class_writer.py**

```
import module_example
from module_example import ClassExample

included_module = ["module_example"]
d = {}
for name, val in globals().items():
    if name in included_module:
        if "__module__" in dir(val):
            d["module"] = val.__module__
            d["class"] = name

#d = {'module': module_example, 'class': ClassExample}

import pickle
filehandler = open("imports.pkl","wb")
pickle.dump(d, filehandler)
filehandler.close()
```

**module_class_reader.py**

```
import pickle
filehandler = open("imports.pkl",'rb')
d = pickle.load(filehandler)
filehandler.close()

def reload_class(module_name, class_name):
    mod = __import__(module_name, fromlist=[class_name])
    reload(mod)
    return getattr(mod, class_name)

if "class" in d and "module" in d: 
    reload(__import__(d["module"]))
    ClassExample = reload_class(d["module"], d["class"])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the unpickled class to be the exact same object that was pickled, you'd have to store the class's code (using an external library like [dill](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill), for example).

Otherwise, there is no way with standard pickle to store a reference to a class that will 'survive' a refactoring.

Comment: I don t need the same object.  But I need a reference to the class.  So that I can instantiate a new object based on that reference.  If that class name andor location is refactored, I'd want the reference to reflect that as well.  Any way it can be done?

Comment: @Emily: There's no way Python would be able to tell that the new class and the old class are "the same class" after such a refactoring.